# Confused about the Auxiliary Conditions of a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am currently trying to solve a problem, but it's not clear to me what the question is asking. The question reads:

> Suppose that any solution u(x,y) of the PDE:
>   $$au_x+bu_y=0$$
>   Satisfies $u(1, 2)=u(3, 6)$. What is $\frac{a}{b}$?

Now I know that:
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = \frac{b}{a}$$
I also know that the general solution to the PDE is given by:
$$u(x,y) = f(bx-ay)$$
How can I conclude what $\frac{a}{b}$ is? Am I missing something very obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says that *any* solution has to satisfy the condition. The only way to guarantee this is if the argument in $f$ is the same at $(1,2)$ and $(3,6)$, giving
$$ b-2a = 3b-6a, $$
from which you can deduce the value of $a/b$.

Comment: Wow, I feel like a fool, thats very obvious. Thanks! I'll accept your answer when I'm able to